# Query with asp.net total session using WMI

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have developed one console application and use WMI query as per below

> queryCollection = ExecuteWMIQuery("Select SessionsActive from
>   Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications");

I have add this console application in startup task to send data from azure application, it will increase asp.net total session value as we open application by URL immediately but it will not decrease immediately that value when we close that application!

what should be reason for this issue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Azure Startup Tasks are logically divided into 3 types: [Background, Simple, Foreground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh124132.aspx). If your task should be always running, you shall never return from your Main() method in your console application, and you shall define this startup task as Background.

As I do understand what you mean by

> ".. as we open application by URL .."

, I don't understand what you mean by

> "... when we close that application"

. So I can't understand what kind of issue are you facing.

Could you be more specific and describe the problem in more details so I'll be able to provide more valuable information.

I also can't understand what do you mean by

> "startup task to send data from azure application"

. If you want to monitor some perfomrance counters you can do that with the integrated [Windows Azure Diagnostics and Monitoring agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411542.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i want to monitor asp.net total session for azure application from my web application. I have useed WMI query, now it's not feasible to change diagnostics

Comment: Hi, what is _total session for azure application_ and where does your "web application" reside?
Is "total session" the total number of sessions? is it the total size of your session objects?
First, when you are developing for Windows Azure it is recommended that you put your session out of process. i.e. use the [link](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/System.Web.Providers) to put your session in SQL Azure.
You don't have to change anything in your code, you can configure the monitoring with just adding a special config file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg604918.aspx